# Change Location of Personal Folder

Tags: windows-8.1, user-profiles

I've set up a VM, where I only allow local user profiles via group policy.
If I log in with my domain account, the location of the "Personal"-Folder which is by default "Documents" always points to a network location. I've tried to change the registry key, but as soon as I log out and in again it will be set back to the network location.

Anybody has an Idea how to change this Setting permanently?

Comment: Which group policy have you applied?. The group policy precedence order works like this: 1. Local Group Policy, 2. Sites, 3. Domain GP, 4. OU. So check whether any of this Group Policy taking precedence. Also, the group policy get refreshed and forces the policy effect when you log off and log in back. Hope this information helps.

Comment: I've enabled the Option "Only allow local user profiles" and "Prevent Roaming Profile changes from propagating to the server"